# laravel 4 send data from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I have validated and authenticated a user and upon authentication I redirect him to the 'dashboard view file'.

What I want know is how do I send that user's data along with the redirected command.

My function looks like this:

```
if($validator->passes()) {
/-- validate user --/
return Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', 'Thanks for registering!');
```

I would appreciate it if someone helped me add the user's data.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it:

```
$user = User::find(1);

return Redirect::to('users/login')
       ->withMessage('Thanks for registering!');
       ->withUser($user);
```

And get it in your controller

```
$user = Session::get('user');
```

Or you could just pass the id

```
return Redirect::to('users/login')
       ->with('message', 'Thanks for registering!');
       ->with('user_id', $user->id);
```

And search for it again

```
$user = User::find(Session::get('user_id'));
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio! You rock :D